# Compound drawable in a TextView is stretching beyond the image size

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I am creating a menu in an Android app with several list items and corresponding icons. The problem that I'm having is that the icons are being stretched beyond the image size for some reason. I have created a menu like this before without such a problem, and I essentially copied the code over to this new project, primarily only changing the image names and string names.

Here is the code from the menu layout for a single list item:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listItemCardTransactions"
    style="@style/NavigationMenuItem"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_card_transaction_menu_icon_normal"
    android:text="@string/card_transactions" />
```

Here is the NavigationMenuItem style:

```
<style name="NavigationMenuItem">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/menu_list_item_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/menu_list_item_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/menu_list_item_padding</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/menu_list_item_left_padding</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_navigation_item</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_menu_item</item>
</style>
```

Here are the dimensions:

```
<dimen name="text_size_menu_item">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_list_item_padding">6dip</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_list_item_left_padding">12dip</dimen>
```

And here is what the menu looks like right now (I know there are several other problems but those aren't my concern right now). You can see the stretching problem best when you drag-and-drop the image to get the full view:
[image: slide out menu problem]

And what the icon is supposed to look like (this one is grey since I wasn't sure how to easily make the white one visible on a white background):

[image: icon]

Anyone know what might be causing the image to stretch past its dimensions like this?

Comment: I don't see anything that is constraining the size of the image, only the padding. As a result the image will take up as much space as it needs.

Comment: That is problem -- the image is taking MORE space than it needs. You can see the small card icon I posted is crisp and clear, but if you expand the image of the menu, you will see that same image is stretched out, which blurs the edges.

Maybe I didn't explain that clearly in my question?

Comment: If you want more control over the appearance of the image, I suggest you use an ImageView and TextView inside a LinearLayout for each item.

Comment: Still doesn't work. :/ Image is still stretching. And when I remove the image, the height of the list item is smaller, so it's not stretching to fill some kind of vacuum. I can't for the life of me understand why it's stretching

Answer (score 0):

I would follow Barry's advise in the comments, ie use an `ImageView` + `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` for each item. However, to solve the "the height of the list item is smaller", you could try adding the following attribute to the `ImageView`:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

If I'm not mistaken, this should effectively make sure that the view bounds is actually based on the content of the image, and not the aspect ratio (ie, it won't change the height beyond the maximum height of the image itself due to "scaling").

Hope that helps (and also makes a bit sense).